# How can I identify a specific property in a Grip App Template?

Tags: javascript, html, windows-8, visual-studio-2012, winjs

I'm developing an App for Windows Store and I have done some changes in the code the first one in *data.js*:

```
var sampleItems = [
        { group: sampleGroups[0], itemClass: "item2", title: "Pupusas:", subtitle: "Item Subtitle: 1", description: itemDescription, content: itemContent, backgroundImage: "/images/dishes/horizontal/comidas.jpg" },
        { group: sampleGroups[0], itemClass: "item", title: "Atol Shuco:", subtitle: "Item Subtitle: 2", description: itemDescription, content: itemContent, backgroundImage: "/images/dishes/thumbnails/bebidas/atol_shuco.jpg" },
        { group: sampleGroups[0], itemClass: "item", title: "Pan con Pollo:", subtitle: "Item Subtitle: 3", description: itemDescription, content: itemContent, backgroundImage: "/images/dishes/thumbnails/comidas/pan_pollo.jpg" },
        { group: sampleGroups[0], itemClass: "item", title: "Nuegados de Huevo:", subtitle: "Item Subtitle: 4", description: itemDescription, content: itemContent, backgroundImage: "/images/dishes/thumbnails/postres/nuegados.jpg" },
        { group: sampleGroups[0], itemClass: "item", title: "Frijoles Borrachos:", subtitle: "Item Subtitle: 5", description: itemDescription, content: itemContent, backgroundImage: "/images/dishes/thumbnails/comidas/frijoles_borrachos.jpg" }];
```

As you can see I have added a property called *itemClass* which determinate, the class of CSS that I'm going to use, and this is the result:
http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/getfile/214473

I know it works good but my problem is that all the pictures that you see are items and I need that the larges ones must be *groups*, I have the codes for groups and items for the groupedItem.js although I don't know how to merge them, this is the codes, both must be in the  *_initializeLayout: function (listView, viewState)* in the *else*:
This is for the items:

```
            listView.itemDataSource = Data.items.dataSource;
            listView.groupDataSource = Data.groups.dataSource;
```

This is for the groups:

```
        listView.itemDataSource = Data.groups.dataSource;
        listView.groupDataSource = null;
```

I would like to know, how can I identify "item2"? And chose the groups inside of the items.

Comment: What do you mean by "I need that the larges ones must be groups"? Do you only want to display the larger ones and not the smaller ones?

Comment: I need to display both but the larges ones are Groups not items:
        var sampleGroups = [
            { key: "group3", title: "Comidas:", subtitle: "Group Subtitle: 3", backgroundImage: mediumGray, description: "/images/dishes/vertical/comidas.jpg" }
        ];
Because when I chose one of them it'll show me the options that it has

Comment: I need to display both because the small ones are the Top 5 of the Dishes and the other ones are the Groups for example: Dishes, Drinks or Desserts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `args.detail.itemIndex`  for the items index. This is the right way to get the index; the item you're getting from the `getAt` call is your data item, which unless you've put an index on it, won't have an index property.